# How do I add hover highlighting to Bokeh Step Chart

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I am working to try and replicate code similar to the second graph from this http://fortune.com/fortune500/visualizations/?iid=recirc_f500landing-zone1

There is the default Step Chart in Bokeh, but it does not want to let me add glyphs.

I would like code something like this

```
from bokeh.charts import Step, show, output_file

# build a dataset where multiple columns measure the same thing
data = dict(
       stamp=[.33, .33, .34, .37, .37, .37, .37, .39, .41, .42,
              .44, .44, .44, .45, .46, .49, .49],
       postcard=[.20, .20, .21, .23, .23, .23, .23, .24, .26, .27,
                 .28, .28, .29, .32, .33, .34, .35]
   )

# create a step chart where each column of measures receives a unique color and dash style
step = Step(data, y=['stamp', 'postcard'],
        dash=['stamp', 'postcard'],
        color=['stamp', 'postcard'],
        title="U.S. Postage Rates (1999-2015)",
        ylabel='Rate per ounce', legend=True)

selected_line = Line(line_alpha=1, line_color="firebrick")
nonselected_line = Line(line_alpha=0.2, line_color="blue")

step.add_glyph(data,
           step,
           selection_glyph=selected_line,
           nonselection_glyph=nonselected_line
)

output_file("steps.html")

show(step)
```

I have tried each way from this page http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs is there a way to build this plot without the Chart library?

Answer (score 2):

**Step chart**
To create this without the bokeh.charts library, you can just use multi line, see http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines. You just have to manually create the corresponding x value for each y.

Essentially if the y value changes it should have the same x value as the previous y value, otherwise increment the x value. That should create the correct data.

**Higlight on hover:**
You can get quite close to the desired effect using the multi line glyph.
It has an in built hover color and alpha setting, so that is taken care of quite easily. The only thing it doesn't do is snap to the nearest line. Not sure if it is possible without custom javascript but i could be wrong.

Example code attached below.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,y_range=(0.2,0.5))


y_vals = [0.22,0.22,0.25,0.25,0.26,0.26,0.27,0.27]
y_vals2 = [y*1.4 for y in y_vals]
x_vals = [0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]
data_dict = {'x':[x_vals,x_vals],
             'y':[y_vals,y_vals2],
             'color':["firebrick", "navy"],
             'alpha':[0.1, 0.1]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data_dict)

p.multi_line('x','y',source=source,
             color='color', alpha='alpha', line_width=4,
             hover_line_alpha=1.0,hover_line_color='color')

p.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False,
                      line_policy='nearest',
                      tooltips=None))
show(p)
```

Comment: Note that since this answer the stable `bokeh.plotting` API added a `step` glyph method, but as of Bokeh 1.4 it does not yet support hover interaction.